# If $x=a$ is not an inflection point and $f''(a)=0$, is $f(a)$ a local extremum?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Knowing that $f''(a)=0$ doesn't say much about the behavior of $f$ around $a$, since it could be a extremum or inflection point (is there any other possibility?). But if we also know that $f(a)$ is not an inflection point, can we conclude that $f(a)$ is a local extremum?

Also, what happens if $f''(a)$ does not exist and we know it is not an inflection point?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I presume you are talking about $a$ such that $f'(a)=0$. There might be holes in the below that might be exploited by a nice pathological example but I will plough on and take my medicine if it comes! I assume that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable.

Suppose that $f''(a)$ is not an inflection point but $f''(a)=0$. This means that the concavity does not change sign at $x=a$. Suppose that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable. We have a closed interval $I$ containing $a$ such that either $f''(I)\geq 0$ or $f''(I)\leq 0$. If there is a smaller interval $J\subset I$ such that $f''(J)=0$ then we can conclude that $f_{\left|J\right.}$ is a constant and so $a$ is an extremum.

Consider the set $K=I\cap (a,\infty)$ the points to the right of $a$ but not including $a$ and suppose that $f''(K)=0$. By anti-differentiating $f''(x)$ on $K$ you will see that this implies that $f_{\left|K\right.}$ is constant. Take a non-empty complement $C:=I\cap(b,a)$ such that $f''(x)$ is never zero (if you can't refer to the above argument.) Suppose without loss of generality that $f''(C)>0$. This implies that $f'$ is strictly increasing 'up' to zero at $x=a$ so in fact $f'(C)<0$. Therefore $x=a$ is an extremum.

Finally suppose without loss of generality that there is an interval $I$ containing $x=a$ such that $f''(I)>0$. Again this implies that $f'$ is strictly increasing up to zero at $x=a$ and thereafter. That is $f$ is decreasing up to $x=a$ and increasing thereafter. Therefore $x=a$ is an extremum.

> **Question 1**: What happens if $f''$ is not continuous.

For your second problem I think that you need to look at

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right) & \text{ if }x\neq0\\ 0 &\text{ if }x=0\end{array}\right..$$

I am guessing that something that looks like the above will answer the dropping of the assumption that $f''$ is continuous.

I am led to believe (see link below) that

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^4\sin\left(\frac1x\right) & \text{ if }x\neq0\\ 0 &\text{ if }x=0\end{array}\right..$$

has $f'(0)=0$, $f''(0)=0$ but is neither a local extremum nor point of inflection.

http://math.berkeley.edu/~scanez/courses/math104/summer10/Home/Home_files/practice-final-solns.pdf